# Как оптимально удалить элементы массива содержащие элементы другого массива?

Tags: python, массивы

Подскажите, как оптимально удалить элементы массива, содержащие элементы другого массива?

Есть 2 массива:

```
arr1 = ['hello', 'world', 'test', 'lalala']
arr2 = ['el', 'es']
```

Мне нужно получить массив: `['world', 'lalala']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = [x for x in arr1 if not any([x.find(y)>=0 for y in arr2])]
print(res)
```

> ['world', 'lalala']

**UPDATE**

более простой и быстрый, но чуть менее универсальный вариант от CrazyElf

```
res = [x for x in arr1 if not any(y in x for y in arr2)]
```

Comment: Разве `any([x.find(y)>=0 for y in arr2])` оптимально по времени? Он же будет перебирать весь массив arr2, даже если нашел совпадение в самом начале

Comment: это единственный минус моего решения. но мне кажется, что оно все равно будет быстрее вашего.

Comment: Так у меня же тоже самое, что и у вас, только второй цикл брекается, если находит первое совпадение, разве нет?

Comment: не совсем. у вас еще две проверки переменных, и по присвоению на каждый уровень цикла. Ну и потом. list comprehension быстрее for.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: Кстати, выход из цикла при нахождении первого совпадения - идея хорошая, особенно, если список поиска большой.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Воспользовался вашим вариантом.

Comment: @strawdog Непонятно только, зачем так сложно через `find`, когда можно написать просто `y in x`, и квадратные скобки внутри круглых не нужны )

Comment: @CrazyElf и действительно. я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

В самом плохом случае все равно придется для каждого элемента массива `arr1` проходиться по всему массиву `arr2`, но можно сократить время с помощью остановки второго цикла, если произошло совпадение. Выглядит это примерно так:

```py
answer = []
for i in arr1:
    match = False
    for j in arr2:
        if j in i:
            match = True
            break # Вот здесь мы перестаем перебирать массив arr2, ибо уже есть совпадение
    if not match:
        answer.append(i)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

поскольку элементы списков - это строки, то почему бы не попробовать регулярку:

```
from re import search

res = list(filter(lambda x: not search(fr'{"|".join(arr2)}', x), arr1))
```

правда по времени это решение проигрывает [решению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383496/457260) от strawdog:

*10.4 µs ± 44.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)*

против:

*5.67 µs ± 79.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)*

но самое быстрое оказалось [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383499/457260) от mazzz3r:

*1.61 µs ± 4.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)*

p.s. тест времени проводился на примере из вопроса.

Comment: А вы попробуйте учесть мой комментарий к решению strawdog, оно должно стать быстрее по идее

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, так стало быстрее: _4.51 µs ± 33.9 ns per loop_ на том же примере

Comment: Хм, не настолько быстрее, как я полагал, надо самому глянуть. По идее any с генератором точно так же должно досрочно выходить из цикла